# AdornerDecorator for WPF Window changes offset of controls

Tags: .net, wpf, window, styles, visual-studio-designer

I have the following window definition

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Style="{StaticResource ShapedWindow}"
        Title="Title">
    <Grid Name="grid1" />
</Window>
```

with the following style and template definition

```
<Style x:Key="ShapedWindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="300" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="300" />
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ShapedWindowTemplate}"></Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ShapedWindowTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <!--<AdornerDecorator>
        <ContentPresenter />
    </AdornerDecorator>-->
</ControlTemplate>
```

which produces the following window in the designer

[image: Window before control template]

When I remove the comments from the template definition the grid doesn't seem to be rendered in the same position? What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: How does it appear at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this behavior in the **VS2010 Designer** a couple of times and I'm pretty sure it's a bug.

With an empty **Template**, there is nothing to render so you shouldn't be able to see the `Grid` at all. When you remove the comments in your ControlTemplate, the effect is most likely a bug in the `VS2010 Designer` which happends everytime you set the **Template** for a `Window` so I don't think you're actually missing anything.
It'll occur even if you use the default Window Template, created in **Expression Blend**

Here's a comparison between **VS2010 Designer** and **Expression Blend 4** using the Default Template for a `Window` so as you can see, this really looks like a bug

[image]

*Note: The exact same thing happends when you use set the Template for a `GroupBox`, even if the ControlTemplate you set is identical to the default Template*